# Sticky header with scrollable content height does not fit inside card body

Tags: css, scroll, sticky

I am trying to make my table header fixed with rest of the table body scrollable in my react application.
This I have been able to achieve using the following css

```
// Parent Container
.Table-Container {
  max-height: 60vh; //Making my table height unresponsive for some reason
  min-height: 40vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 1rem;
}

// Styling and posiition for table header 
.tableHeader .th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

My layout is something like this.

[Card is expanding because of the values assigned to table height to make it scrollable and header sticky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vdbo.png)

[I don't want my wrapper content to scroll. The card height should not expand outside the remaining space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G23H8.png)

[Ideally, I want header and footer fixed and the remaining space should be utilised by the breadcrumb, Filter buttons for the table(if any) and my table itself (again with fixed header) with the ability to auto expand/shrink based on the available space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOTbT.png)

I want the table height to fit inside the cardbody(parent div) automatically, but without assigning height, the scroll wouldn't work. It is only considering height in px or vh. Setting the height to auto also wouldn't work.

I want this to be responsive across different screen sizes.
Declaring a height in vh is also coming in the way of making it responsive.

Would appreciate any help or direction on this.

Thanks

I tried to set the height to my main-content like this

```
.main-content {
height: calc(100vh - #{$header-height} - #{$footer-height})
padding: calc(#{$header-height} + #{$grid-gutter-width})
    calc(#{$grid-gutter-width} / 2) $footer-height
    calc(#{$grid-gutter-width} / 2);
}
```

The card is still expanding outside the defined height of the parent.

I even tried using box-sizing: border-box but this wouldn't have any impacts either.

When I use this logic in a normal html + css this works perfectly,
However in react it is not behaving as expected.

Comment: Did you find out a clean solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have written @media query to handle this for now which works for most of the cases but is not an elegant solution.